# innodb_memcache how to set daemon_memcached_w_batch_size

Tags: mysql, innodb

In innodb with memcached plugin:

Found a lot talking about this will help with performance,but did not find what commands to set this value

how to set: daemon_memcached_w_batch_size to differen value?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add a line in my.cnf if you have linux or my.ini on windows

```
daemon_memcached_w_batch_size='you value'
```

Comment: I added this --daemon_memcached_w_batch_size='you value' when I'm running my script, for example: ./test.py --daemon_memcached_w_batch_size='you value'            Will this solve the problew? Do I have to also add daemon_memcached_w_batch_size='you value' to my-defalt.cnf? Thanks for responding.

Comment: I got this. sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf   not in the my-default.cnf